# How do I quote RPG.SE material outside the site?

Tags: support

**How do I quote Questions and/or Answers outside the site that I've written myself for the site?**

Secondarily, how exactly do I quote - again, outside the site - Q&A by others? And what's the difference between the two, if there's any?

I know "user contribution is 'cc-wiki' and 'attribution required'" (both are stated in the footer, with links to explanations), but I seem to remember a more detailed official source on this, only I can't seem to find it. Does anyone have a link, or could someone sum the process up briefly?

(Disclaimer: I've got a bad cold at the moment, and my google fu is seriously impaired by that. Sorry.)

Comment: You might be looking for [something like this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers), which pretty much restates the points provided in the CC license. The gist of it is, as you said, that you need to provide attribution, such as a link back to the Question/Answer.

Answer (score 4):

For questions you've written yourself, you are the copyright holder and have no restrictions on your use thereof. It's eternally licensed to SEI but that only affects their ability to distribute it, not yours.

For questions by others or in publication, the requirements for attribution are [here](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)

Essentially, as long as you mention it's from SE, you're allowed to republish the content, even for profit. The only restriction is that if you remix it or adapt it, the remix/adaptation is licensed under the same license.

Comment: The attribution itself has [some extra requirements](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) specified in our ToS. Specifically: you have to link to the authors and question, show the author names, indicate the material's from SO... _and_ the links must not be nofollowed.

Comment: That last bit about nofollowing has received [some](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209250/152515) [attention](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209269/152515) on meta - because CC doesn't necessarily let you make that demand - but it appears it's possible that [the old CC license did](http://web.archive.org/web/20130413022926/http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/) - _"You must attribute the work in the manner specified by the author or licensor"_ - and then CC modified that license to [no longer say that](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/).

Comment: What is “nofollow”?

Comment: @Kryan: an attribute on an HTML link that tells search engines to ignore the link, so a nofollow link to SE doesn't give SE any extra google-juice.